# How do I move a clicked QCheckBox widget up above other checkboxes?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am making a search filter for my PyQt6 project. One of the filter elements is supposed to display all available options in a search category.

[image: Example]

Each option is a QCheckBox that is added into QVBoxLayout. After the layout is populated with options, it is installed as a layout manager on QWidget that is then set as a QScrollArea widget.
**I want a QCheckBox option to be moved above other unchecked options upon being clicked.**

[image: Like that]

What is the way to do that?
And on a related note, **is it possible to sort QCheckBox'es alphabetically by means of PyQt** (for now I am just passing a sorted list with texts for options)? I guess I'll need it if I want checked options to be sorted as well, and when an option is unchecked for it to be put back in an alphabetically correct position.

Here is my code so far:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from database_handler import DatabaseHandler


class SearchParamGroup(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, group_title, db_column):
        super(SearchParamGroup, self).__init__()

        title_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(group_title)
        reset_button = QtWidgets.QLabel('RESET')  # It is just a placeholder for now
        title_and_reset_hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        title_and_reset_hbox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        title_and_reset_hbox.addWidget(title_label)
        title_and_reset_hbox.addWidget(reset_button)

        options_box = self.create_options_box(db_column)

        group_vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        group_vbox.addLayout(title_and_reset_hbox)
        group_vbox.addWidget(options_box)

        self.setLayout(group_vbox)

    @staticmethod
    def create_options_box(db_column_from_init):
        scroll_area_widget_vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        group_options = DatabaseHandler.get_distinct_values(db_column_from_init)
        for option_name in group_options:
            option_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(option_name)
            scroll_area_widget_vbox.addWidget(option_checkbox)

        scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scroll_area_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scroll_area_widget.setLayout(scroll_area_widget_vbox)
        scroll_area.setWidget(scroll_area_widget)

        return scroll_area
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't prefer to use [QListWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html)?

Comment: As a side note, I would not suggest to move items when they're checked, as it would be very confusing and annoying; when there are a lot of items and lot of them are supposed to be checked, it's easy to click the wrong one by mistake. Imagine you want to check an item way down to the list, you click a nearby item by mistake without realizing it, you do *not* see that because that wrongly checked item has been moved above, and you may assume that you just didn't click at all; if you selected lots of items, you may not see the wrong one in the list. And the same could happen in the opposite way.

Comment: Suppose that you have a lot of checked items on top, then you want to uncheck one of them, but then you click the wrong one by mistake: you have to scroll down to find it and check it back again, and that's assuming that you remember what item that was (maybe you checked *a lot* of items, or some of them were automatically selected). If you want to display a "summary" of checked items, a better solution may be to use a separate widget that only shows the list of currently selected items, for instance a read only line edit, or another QListWidget.

Comment: @musicamante, I'll look into QListWidget. Thank you! As for my decision to do it the way I describe, I base it on my user experience. It turned out to be very handy when I want to slightly change search parameters. I just don't need to scroll all the way down to find a checked item. They are all here. An accident click on an item is a rare occasion, so benefits outweigh potential inconveniences. However, it is something that works for me personally. I'll consider your suggestions. Thanks again :)

Comment: I understand what you feel about *your* habits, but remember that what we personally feel "good" is rarely what's generally accepted (as a convention) or preferred (UX is quite a complex subject, and there's a whole StackExchange for that, [ux.se]; I'd suggest you to look into all that). I often find myself asking whether a UX choice I'm making is just valid for me or the best for users, as I know that everybody is different and it's important to properly balance functionality, common convention and, most importantly, intuitiveness and ease of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A basic solution

The simplicity of QBoxLayout allows to easily change the order of items just by calling or [`insertWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qboxlayout.html#insertWidget) or [`addWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qboxlayout.html#addWidget) (which internally calls `insertWidget(-1, widget)`), because that always guarantees that the widget will be put at the given position, even if it is already part of the layout manager.

Considering that, you can add the check boxes to an internal list that will preserve the original order, and then "add" them again based on their checked state.

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CheckBoxSort(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        container = QWidget()
        self.setWidget(container)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(container)
        self.checks = []
        for l in letters:
            check = QCheckBox(l * 10)
            self.checks.append(check)
            layout.addWidget(check)
            check.toggled.connect(self.sortChecked)

    def sortChecked(self):
        checked = []
        unchecked = []
        for check in self.checks:
            if check.isChecked():
                checked.append(check)
            else:
                unchecked.append(check)

        layout = self.widget().layout()
        for check in checked + unchecked:
            layout.addWidget(check)


app = QApplication([])
test = CheckBoxSort()
test.show()
app.exec()
```

### An alternative solution, using item views

Note that what you're showing is a "list of items", and Qt actually provides that: QListView (with a related model) or even QListWidget (a lower level class that implements the model on its own).

Such lists are normally better suited for situations where *lots* of items are being shown, as they provide a more abstract and powerful way to interact with their contents.

Here is a possible implementation, similar to the above:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ListCheckSort(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.allItems = []
        for l in letters:
            item = QListWidgetItem(l * 10)
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            self.addItem(item)
            self.allItems.append(item)

        self.itemChanged.connect(self.sortChecked)

    def sortChecked(self):
        checked = []
        unchecked = []
        for item in self.allItems:
            if item.checkState():
                checked.append(item)
            else:
                unchecked.append(item)

        # Qt views normally scroll to the item when it's selected and 
        # moved, so we keep a reference to the vertical scroll bar value
        # and restore it right after
  
        vb = self.verticalScrollBar().value()
        for item in checked + unchecked:
            self.addItem(self.takeItem(self.row(item)))
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(vb)


app = QApplication([])
test = ListCheckSort()
test.show()
app.exec()
```

There's one slight difference: item views normally change their "check state" only when the user *exactly* clicks on the check box rectangle, which is different from normal check boxes that also toggle their state when the user clicks the "label" next to its indicator.

We can work around that too:

```py
class ListCheckSort(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.itemClicked.connect(self.toggleItem)

    # ...

    def toggleItem(self, item):
        if not item:
            return
        if item.checkState():
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
```

Note that `if not item`: that is caused by the fact that `clicked` signal is fired *after* the item check state has been toggled, and since the view emits the signal with the item under the mouse cursor when the mouse button has been released (and at that point, the item is not there anymore), `item` becomes invalid.

### UX considerations

The above brings us to a different issue, related to the *User Experience* (UX).

In my experience (not just as an user with personal experience, but considering the UX subject objectively), such an approach would not be very good, for many reasons:

- users need a visual confirmation of their actions, not an assumption: it's quite easy to click the wrong item in a very long list, and it's even easier to do that with touch devices (including touch pads used in laptops) and the user might click on the wrong item without knowing; moving an item when it's toggled (possibly outside of the currently visible list) means that the user has to *assume* that their action was successful or that they didn't do anything at all:

  - if they clicked an unchecked item, they probably wouldn't realize it immediately ("I clicked but nothing happened"), and if they checked lots of items they might not see an unwanted item in the "checked" list;
  - if they clicked a checked item by mistake, they will need to scroll down to it in order to check it again: that's assuming that they remember what item that was, and that items are sorted in a logical way: in either cases, that's annoying (and the user should not be annoyed by the UI);
- never forget about keyboard navigation: while most users use touch and mouse to interact with a GUI, a lot of them still use tabs and arrows in order to easily navigate the UI; both of the solutions provided above would be very confusing to them:

  - with the layout approach, the focus will be kept on the checked item, and Qt doesn't update the focus order when widgets are moved within the same layout: while this means that using tab/arrow keys will focus on the next/previous check box of the original order, that would also be inconsistent, because the tab order will just "jump around" the container widgets;
  - with the item approach, the focus is kept on the selected items, meaning that it will be moved on top (or the middle) of the item list, making keyboard interaction extremely annoying; note that the same would happen even if the above layout aspect would update the focus chain order;

In conclusion, I would highly discourage such an approach, both as a user and as a developer. A better solution could be to provide a further widget that visually displays the current selection (for instance, a basic QLineEdit set in read only mode that lists all selected items, or a separate QListWidget that does the same), or eventually find another alternative.

A possibility could be to create "proxy items" that would be always aligned on top when items are checked, and deleted when they (or their "original" item) is unchecked. While that would certainly be a much complex implementation, it would also provide a UX that would have a more consistent behavior, keeping proper interaction and user satisfaction.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer!
Both approaches do the job perfectly! Actually I am a little disappointed I couldn't come up with at least the layout solution by myself. It looks so simple when pointed out :) Really like the idea here. After you suggested to take a look on QListWidget, I was working in that direction. I couldn't understand why the app crashed when I clicked on the checkbox instead of the item text. Your `if not item` note clarified that. So it is another thanks from me :)

Comment: The only thing I'd like to note is that it seems there is a little error in the second solution. It was not working until I changed two lines from `if item.checkState():` to `if item.checkState() == Qt.CheckState.Checked:` (I guess it will be just `Qt.Checked` for PyQt5), as CheckState is returned.

Comment: And I think you convinced me to do all that in another way. I will be working on the "proxy items" approach now. The app I am developing is more of an educational project and is intended for my personal use, so I was considering my preferences in the first place. However, it looks like with "proxy items" it is going to be even better. Thanks again!

Comment: @HetairaThaïs You're welcome! To answer to your second comment, the latest versions of PyQt5 are migrating to the full namespace Enum usage that has been introduced in PyQt6 (and, similarly but with a more permissive process, in PySide6) which are more strict about the enum types: it's possible that `Qt.CheckState` doesn't provide anymore a truthfulness implementation as it used to do before; originally, PyQt used "fake" enums, that used the simple integer value, so `if item.checkState():` was conceptually the same as `if 0:` if it returned `Qt.Unchecked` or `if 2:` for `Qt.Checked`.

Comment: @HetairaThaïs About the third comment, I tried to implement the proxy items approach, but it was becoming too convoluted for the scope of the question. Be careful with it, as inserting or removing items while mouse event are still being processed could cause inconsistent or unexpected behavior. I realize that it would become much more complex than the above solutions, and since it's just for a personal usage maybe it's not worth it... unless you want to do that for learning purposes, which is usually a good reason to do things (but not always to *actually* do them) ;-)

Comment: I see. PyQt has so many things to be aware about... I am gonna try this new approach if anything comes of it at all. Thank you!